# Que signifie exactement l'expression « et basta » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, registre-familier

Je voudrais connaître les significations de l'expression « et basta ». Qu'est ce que cette expression signifie exactement ?

Comment: Pour certains d'entre nous, la réponse à ta question se trouve en réalité [par ici](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et..._basta_!)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cette interjection vient de l'italien *basta*. Elle signifie *et c'est assez !*, *cela suffit !*.

[Le TLF donne plus de détails](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/basta). On y apprend notamment que *bast* et *baste* sont également utilisés, mais *basta* demeure la forme la plus répandue.

Answer (score 6):

Cette expression signifie: *cela suffit*.

Dans *Shakespeare* nous avons

> Basta, content thee: for I haue it full.

*(Tam. Shr. i. i. 203)*

Comment: +1 pour l'universalité de cette expression.

Answer (score 4):

Beaucoup citent ici l'italien "*basta*" mais l'espagnol n'est pas en reste avec l'adverbe "*bastante*" signifiant "*suffisamment*". [Ce lien](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/basta) parle aussi d'un ancien mot français "*baster*" synonyme de "*suffire*".

Ça sent donc à plein nez le mot d'origine gréco-romaine en "*bast-*" + quelque chose derrière (latin "*bastare*" ?) signifiant "*suffire*". Ce mot aurait alors donné des mots en "*bast-*" + autre chose derrière comme "*basta*" dans les langues romanes (dérivant du latin).

Answer (score 3):

J'ajouterais les interprétations « on n'en parle plus ! », « c'est réglé », ou « fiche le camp ! ».